# How to create custom cms page layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, cms-pages

In Magento 2, is there any solution to creating a custom layout XML file for custom cms page?

I want to add XML code and CSS and Js only for my custom cms page.

I know about there is one field available at admin side. But, XML code is the little bit large. So, it's not a better way.

Can anyone guide me how to create it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a custom CMS page layout file by using this below way.

File name should be like this :

**`cms_page_view_selectable_<CMS Page Identifier>_<Layout Update Name>.xml`**

**=> For eg :** If your cms page identifier is **customhome**, then file name should be **cms_page_view_selectable_customhome_customhomelayout.xml**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html
search :
For CMS Pages:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add your css and js file tag here-->   
    </head> 
    <body>
            <!-- Add your reference container, ref block etc. here -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Can you please tell me any error log generate or?

Comment: No log file generated about error

Comment: It's my mistake. File name was not proper. It's working. Thanks.

Comment: How do I find my "custom cms page identifier"?

Comment: @br4nnigan, it's page's url key

Comment: Typical that this simple task is not anywhere in the whole of official magento 2 'Layout' devdocs!!! Only a less intuitive version "cms_page_view_selectable_<CMS Page Identifier>_<Layout Update Name>.xml".  

Comment: How to do it for cms block?

Comment: To add to this, the xml file you create should be added to the Magento_Cms/layout directory within your theme

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/column-full.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlClass="header" />
        <referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlClass="main-content" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="column-full">
        <label translate="true">Column Full</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

Now you can use `layout="column-full"` in your XML file or you can select "Column Full" in CMS page > Layout Dropdown.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not working for me :(

Comment: I want to create in my custom module. not in theme

Comment: How can I add custom `CSS` in the `column-full.xml`?

Comment: @RafaelPerozin you can't add custom CSS in head with this. This is page_layout (page_layout.xsd) and not layout (page_configuration.xsd). Technically you can add custom css in body with this. But the question is `custom layout XML file for custom cms page`. Which is completely different thing from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom page XML layout file within your custom theme at:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view_id_page-url-key.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a CMS page with URL key `corporate`, create following file worked

`app/code/<VENDOR>/<MODULE_NAME>/view/frontend/layout/cms_corporate_index.xml`