# Magento 2 - How to remove css from specific content pages

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

I am using Magento 2.3.5 and I would like to remove a CSS file from specific Content -> Pages

My **default_head_blocks.xml** file code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- ADD CSS  -->
        <css src="css/styles-m.css"/>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print"/>
        <css src="css/custom-sb.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I would like to remove **custom-sb.css** from some cms pages.

I have created a **Custom Layout Update** file and call it from the **Design section** of the page

My custom layout update file **cms_page_view_selectable_home-grocery_microsite.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <remove src="css/custom-sb.css"/>
        <css src="css/custom-microsite.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

[image]

I did the above things but still, it is not working.
Can someone please help me with this?
Thank you

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/247395/51810 Try using this answer.

Comment: What theme are you currently using? The porto theme is notoriously unreliable when it comes to the new implementation of the custom xml layout updates

Comment: Curious you should try opposite way ? Add css only in specific page that you need instead include all page and remove after that