# edit layou of a specific CMS page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p2

I have a problem and as I am new to magento I decided to turn to you. I am editing the layout of some pages in magento 2, and there is a specific page created in the CMS by the content panel - Pages, which I need to change, and it is only on that page. I tried to find the XML and I think the correct XML must be cms_page_view but I can't edit this xml. Can you help me please?

I tried to edit the xml id from cms_page_view to cms_page_view_id_9.xml, and copied the xml from cms_page_view and added the code I needed to add and it looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container px-0 container-alinhamento" htmlId="teste" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" name="cms_page" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it does not work. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Use this one : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/247395/

Answer (score 0):

You defined the layout filename wrong. Please check this article https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#create-cms-pageproductcategory-specific-selectable-layouts which tells you how to edit layouts of CMS pages:

> For CMS Pages:
> `cms_page_view_selectable_<CMS Page Identifier>_<Layout Update Name>.xml`
> where:
>
> 1. **CMS Page Identifier** is the desired page’s URL Key with “/” symbols replaced with “_”.
> 2. **Layout Update Name** is what is shown as the option for the Custom layout update field of the Design section on the CMS Page Edit page. **For example, a layout update for an “About Us” page will be “cms_page_view_selectable_about-us_AboutUs.xml”.**

> These files must be placed in the appropriate folders for layout XML files. They will be available as Custom Layout Update options for Merchants after flushing the cache.

Comment: I get that / would be swappped with _ via devdocs but what if the url key ends in .html?

Comment: In that case leave it as a dot it seems :)